# Laravel Eloquent Group By Relation Sum()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 models

- Transaction
- Job
- Service

My relations are as follows:

**Transaction Model:**

```
public function job() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Job');
}
```

**Job Model:**

```
public function service() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Service');
}
```

I'm trying to query my transactions table and sum the total value and group by service.

My initial thought was to query Transactions:

```
Transaction::with('job')->groupBy('job.service_id');
```

This doesn't work as job.service_id doesn't exist in the transactions table.

My other thought was to do a callback on the Transaction query and do the query for every service_id in the jobs table - This seems like this would work but it seems quite a long winded process.

My goal output:

- service_id: 1
- total_value: 100
- service_id: 2
- total_value: 300

I would then query the services table for the service name.

Comment: Which table is the `value` column in?

Answer (score -1):

Try this query :

```
Transaction::join('jobs', 'jobs.id', 'transactions.job_id')
    ->join('services', 'services.id', 'jobs.service_id')
    ->select('services.id', \DB::raw('sum(transaction.value)')
    ->groupBy('services.id')
    ->get();
```